# Why SVGZ and gzipped SVG have a huge size difference

Tags: svg, gzip

It is an understanding question. AFAIK SVGZ is a Gzipped SVG file. But, if I compress my SVG file with Gzip I get a file like `myfile.svg.gz`, which has a much lower file size, as after converting SVG to SVGZ (file like `myfile.svgz`)

Here are my file examples:

- Original SVG: https://file.io/aI8bdZsRsgi9, 105kB
- svgz: https://file.io/nnrcJtbQ88Wl, 98kB
- svg.gz: https://file.io/pn2nIco0QfOa, 19kB

Now my question:
What should I do to load SVG files in my website with the minimal possible size:

1. Just add to htaccess

   `AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz`
   `AddEncoding gzip svgz`

Or

2. Gzip SVG before uploading to the server?

I was always assuming, SVGZ is gzipped SVG, until I realized this huge size difference

Comment: The links don't work.

Comment: `svgz` files should have a nearly the same file size as manually gzipped `svg`s – probably the file export in your application has a bug. However, It's easier to use uncompressed svgs and send them gzipped via htacces rules like `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml`. Besides, you should consider to optimize your files via tools like [SVOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) to cut down the actual parsing and rendering time.